# Input value in child component not being updated by setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In this app, I'm fetching images from the Unsplash API (with an Express back end, React front end). On page load, general images appear (rendered inside the [`react-infinite-scroll-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component)), and if you search, a special fetch method (`fetchSearchImages`) is called to get new images. In either case, they're rendered in a `react-infinite-scroll-component` instance.

My problem is that after the form holding the search input is submitted, the search input isn't getting cleared. In the input I have `value={props.inputValue}`, and in the parent component, after the form is submitted `fetchSearchImages` is called. In `fetchSearchImages`, I'm trying to reset the input value with `this.setState()` but the value displayed in the input remains unchanged. I also tried to do so in the `handleSubmit()` else block, and that didn't do anything either.

[View live](https://infinite-scroll-unsplash.herokuapp.com/) | [GitHub repo](https://github.com/nataliecardot/infinite-scroll)

Child search input component:

```
const SearchInput = props => {

  const onSubmit = e => {
    // Prevents GET request/page refresh on submit
    e.preventDefault();
    props.onFormSubmit();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className="control">
        <input autoFocus value={props.inputValue} onChange={e => props.onSearch(e.target.value)} className="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Parent component:

```
export class Images extends Component {
  state = {
    images: [],
    searchImages: [],
    count: 4,
    page: 1,
    searchPage: 1,
    term: '',
    search: false,
    newSearch: false,
    blankSearch: false,
    inputValue: ''
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { page, count } = this.state;
      axios
        .get(`/api/photos?page=${page}&count=${count}`)
        .then(res => this.setState({ images: res.data }));
    // To prevent same images being fetched upon scrolling (in the first call to fetchImages)
    this.setState({ page: page + count });
  }

  fetchImages = () => {
    const { page, count, images } = this.state;
    this.setState({ page: page + 1 });
    axios
      .get(`/api/photos?page=${page}&count=${count}`)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({ images: images.concat(res.data) })
      );
  }

  fetchSearchImages = () => {
    const { searchPage, count, term, searchImages } = this.state;

    this.setState({ searchPage: searchPage + 1, inputValue: '' });

    axios
      .get(`/api/photos/search?term=${term}&page=${searchPage}&count=${count}`)
      .then(res =>
        this.setState({
          searchImages: searchImages.concat(res.data.results)
        })
      );
  }

  // Necessary to place fetchSearchImages in a setState callback to ensure other state is set first
  handleSubmit = () => {
    if (!this.state.inputValue) {
      this.setState({
        images: [],
        blankSearch: true,
        newSearch: false,
        search: false,
        searchImages: [],
        searchPage: 1,
        page: 1,
      }, this.fetchImages);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        term: this.state.inputValue,
        searchImages: [],
        searchPage: 1,
        page: 1,
        search: true,
        newSearch: true
      }, this.fetchSearchImages);
    }
  }

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: e
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>

      <SearchInput onSearch={this.handleInputChange} value={this.state.inputValue} onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />

      <div className="images">
        <InfiniteScroll
          dataLength={this.state.blankSearch ? this.state.images.length : (this.state.newSearch || this.state.search) ? this.state.searchImages.length : this.state.images.length}
          next={this.state.search ? this.fetchSearchImages : this.fetchImages}
          hasMore={true}
          loader={
            <div className="loader-dots">
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
              <span className="loader-dot"></span>
            </div>
          }
        >
        {this.state.newSearch || this.state.search ? this.state.searchImages.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id + Math.random()} image={image} />
        ) : this.state.blankSearch ? this.state.images.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id + Math.random()} image={image} />
        ) : this.state.images.map(image =>
          <Image key={image.id + Math.random()} image={image} />
        )}
      </InfiniteScroll>
      </div>

      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like your input is being properly controlled.

In your `SearchInput` component, you are referencing an invalid prop. You call the prop `value` in the parent, but reference it as `inputValue` in the child.

Change the input to:

```js
<input autoFocus value={props.value} onChange={e => props.onSearch(e.target.value)} className="input" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
```

Or the parent to:

```js
<SearchInput onSearch={this.handleInputChange} inputValue={this.state.inputValue} onFormSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
```